# Multiplying CGPoints using SKTUtils

Tags: swift, sktutils

I'm developing a Sprite Kit game using Swift, loosely following the Ray Wenderlich tutorials found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62049/sprite-kit-tutorial-make-platform-game-like-super-mario-brothers-part-1) and [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62049/sprite-kit-tutorial-make-platform-game-like-super-mario-brothers-part-2), and incorporating the [SKTUtils module](https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils) to allow easy addition/multiplication/division etc. of `CGPoint`s.

The issue I'm finding is that all the online documentation refers to the older, Objective-C version of the module, while the code on Github has been rewritten to use Swift, and there's no accompanying usage guidelines.

The tutorial (written using Objective-C) states that the following code should work:

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)delta {
  CGPoint gravity = CGPointMake(0.0, -450.0);
  CGPoint gravityStep = CGPointMultiplyScalar(gravity, delta);
  self.velocity = CGPointAdd(self.velocity, gravityStep);
  CGPoint velocityStep = CGPointMultiplyScalar(self.velocity, delta);
  self.position = CGPointAdd(self.position, velocityStep);
}
```

Which, loosely translated to Swift, equates to:

```
func update(delta:NSTimeInterval) {
    let gravity:CGPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, -450.0);
    var gravityStep:CGPoint = CGPointMultiplyScalar(gravity * delta)
    self.velocity = self.velocity + gravityStep;
    let velocityStep:CGPoint = CGPointMultiplyScalar(self.velocity, delta)
    self.position = self.position + velocityStep;
}
```

However, the `CGPointMultiplyScalar` function has been changed to simply `*`. There's no accompanying documentation that I can find on how to implement thins, and my approaches aren't working:

```
func update(delta:NSTimeInterval) {
    ...
    var gravityStep:CGPoint = CGPoint(gravity * delta); // nope
    var gravityStep:CGPoint = gravity * delta; // nope
    ...
}
```

Does anyone out there have experience with this and can tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CGPoint extension looks like:

```
public func * (point: CGPoint, scalar: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: point.x * scalar, y: point.y * scalar)
}
```

The scalar parameter needs a CGFloat, but you try to multiply it with an NSTimeInterval, and since there are no implicit conversions, you have to do

```
var gravityStep:CGPoint = gravity * CGFloat(delta)
```

to make it work.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much, I was tearing my hair out!